# How to create dynamically editable Rules with Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: dynamic, visual-studio-2017, workflow-foundation, rules, rule-engine

I wanted to know how I can create declarative rule conditions and rulesets so that I can modify the rules dynamically without having to build my application.

For this I got a lot of solutions, I started with Designer re-hosting, then found that it cannot be used as it will require my application to be compiled.

Then I came to know that, if I use Declarative Rule Conditions, i will be able to create rules which are stored as xml in .rules files and can be modified dynamically.

Then I tried to create the rule using Visual Studio 2017, but I couldn't find a way to do it.
Visual Studio 2017 doesn't support rule creation?

How can I create rule which can be consumed in my ASP.Net application and without having to rebuild my application?

Thanks & Regards,

Dennis Thomas

Comment: While you can load a workflow from XML, you should bear in mind that WF is essentially dead. Even v4.5 back in 2012 (I think) had minimal improvements. If you really need a workflow engine, you should look elsewhere. As for *rules*, you don't need a *Workflow* for this. (WF4 essentially abandoned the rule engine btw). Nor does a workflow engine provide what one would expect in a rule engine.

Comment: Start for your *actual* requirements? What do you mean by rules? Do you really need an engine for this? Wouldn't a rules table do? Or are you looking for an *editor* for rules that call an already created action?

Comment: Thank you Panagiotis for the quick response. The reason I look for a rule engine is, I will create a set of rules and users should be able to edit the rule in the future without a developer's intervention. As you said, if WF abandoned rule engine, let me check whether NRules will work for me. Thank you so much for giving guidance!